# Mongo DB crash by a peak of the CPU Ubuntu 18

Tags: server, virtualbox, cpu, mongodb

**Update:** As requested I am using 18.04.2-Ubuntu and about the MongoDB
[image]
I have a virtual machine running several Node JS projects and a local instance of Mongo DB. The virtual Machine has only 2 GB of RAM. And I'm monitoring the database with the free monitoring provided by mongo DB

The problem occurs randomly, the CPU usage by Mongo DB goes high, and it overcomes the 2GB Ram and crashes. And the error on the logs (which is attached at the end), points to admin.$cmd what appear in other warnings before without another impact. This issue can not happen for a week, and suddenly happens a day 6am when nobody is calling the server. I suspect some internal MongoDB usage.
[image]
Does anyone have a TIP on why the CPU usage peaks appear or how to avoid them? I could always upgrade the VM or use MongoDB atlas but has no sense that this happens in a VM in which traffic is almost unexisting

```
{"t":{"$date":"2023-01-11T07:32:53.117+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":23099,   "ctx":"PeriodicTaskRunner","msg":"Task finished","attr":{"taskName":"DBConnectionPool-cleaner","durationMillis":1437}}

{"t":{"$date":"2023-01-11T07:32:35.867+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":51803,   "ctx":"conn29","msg":"Slow query","attr":{"type":"command","ns":"admin.$cmd","command":{"ismaster":1,"$db":"admin"},"numYields":0,"reslen":304,"locks":{},"remote":"127.0.0.1:53792","protocol":"op_msg","durationMillis":43549}}

{"t":{"$date":"2023-01-11T07:31:52.574+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":51803,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheReap","msg":"Slow query","attr":{"type":"command","ns":"config.transactions","command":{"find":"transactions","filter":{"lastWriteDate":{"$lt":{"$date":"2023-01-11T06:58:42.761Z"}}},"projection":{"_id":1},"sort":{"_id":1},"readConcern":{},"$db":"config"},"planSummary":"EOF","keysExamined":0,"docsExamined":0,"cursorExhausted":true,"numYields":0,"nreturned":0,"queryExecutionEngine":"classic","reslen":108,"locks":{"FeatureCompatibilityVersion":{"acquireCount":{"r":3}},"ReplicationStateTransition":{"acquireCount":{"w":1}},"Global":{"acquireCount":{"r":3}},"Mutex":{"acquireCount":{"r":2}}},"readConcern":{"provenance":"implicitDefault"},"storage":{},"protocol":"op_msg","durationMillis":109845}}
```

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details; please provide, or are you expecting us to guess?  Why ask here, as you've not yet provided anything on-topic given we don't know the OS (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)  nor clues as to what package type of mongo db you're using (*snap*?  *deb*? etc)

Comment: Does your VM have swap space allocated? Read `man free mkswap swapon fstab`